# Cannot append a vector inside a list in R

Tags: r

I have a set of vectors inside a list wherein I want to append certain values to each vector. When I used `append()` outside the loop, it worked perfectly fine but inside a loop it doesn't seem to work.

```
factors <- list(c("K3BG","9"),c("RTCKO","4"))
len <- length(factors)
for (i in 1:length)
{
    rejig_score <- factors[[i]][2]
    rejig_score <- as.numeric(rejig_score)
    if(rejig_score > 5)
    {
         factors[[i]] <- append(factors[[i]],"Approved")
    }
    else
    {
        factors[[i]] <- append(factors[[i]],"Disapproved")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed `1:lenght` to `1:len` inside `for`

```
factors <- list(c("K3BG","9"),c("RTCKO","4"))

len <- length(factors)

for (i in 1:len)
{
  rejig_score <- factors[[i]][2]
  rejig_score <- as.numeric(rejig_score)
  if(rejig_score > 5)
  {
    factors[[i]] <- append(factors[[i]],"Approved")
  }
  else
  {
    factors[[i]] <- append(factors[[i]],"Disapproved")
  }
}

factors

[[1]]
[1] "K3BG"     "9"        "Approved"

[[2]]
[1] "RTCKO"       "4"           "Disapproved"
```

Comment: So the thing is that the when I print the variable factors it works but its not being stored in Global Environment.

Comment: That is very strange, here is alright. There are other code in the script? I recommend also terminate the session and run just the code above again

Comment: That's it for now. Its just this piece of code. Will try it in someone else's IDE as well. Thank you so much for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply`

```
lapply(factors, function(x) c(x, if(as.numeric(x[2]) > 5) 
      "Approved" else "Disapproved"))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "K3BG"     "9"        "Approved"

[[2]]
[1] "RTCKO"       "4"           "Disapproved"
```

---

Or another option is to extract the second element from the `list` and do the comparison outside, create the vector values and append

```
new <- c("Disapproved", "Approved")[1 + 
       (as.numeric(sapply(factors, `[[`, 2)) > 5)]
 Map(c, factors, new)
[[1]]
[1] "K3BG"     "9"        "Approved"

[[2]]
[1] "RTCKO"       "4"           "Disapproved"
```